# Create a new column in a pandas dataframe, performing conditional equations for if the values are positive or negative

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a panda’s data-frame which consists of two columns, the ‘index’ and the ‘price’ column as shown below:
[image: Pandas Data Frame]

I need to create a new column called ‘Log’, where I want to perform two separate operations depending on if the data in the column ‘Price’ is negative or positive. For the rows which are positive I need to perform the following operation:

```
df["Log"] = 10**(df['Price'])
```

And for if the number in the ‘Price’ columns is negative, perform the operation below to take the absolute value of that cell:

```
df["Log"] = -10**(df['Price'].abs())
```

Could you please show me a python code where the above operations could be performed on the original pandas data frame, where the end result should look like the following:

[image: Final expected data frame structure]

I have included the code to create the original dataframe below:

```
# Create dataframe 
cars = {'Index': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
        'Price': [2.266021, 2.160644, -2.266021, 2.103899, 2.019323, 2.134563, 2.193423, 2.495643, 2.129344, 2.876545]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Index', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

Comment: See `np.where()` and for more complex conditional operations `np.select()`.

Comment: Are you really meaning to exponentiate the price and call it the Log? Those are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
import numpy as np 

df["Log"] = np.where(df.Price<0, -10**(df['Price'].abs()), 10**(df['Price']))
```

Answer (score 0):

For positive numbers, `df['Price'].abs()` is the same as just `df['Price']`. It can be expressed without conditionals:

```
df["Log"] = np.sign(df['Price']) * (10**df['Price'].abs())
```